# How is decarburisation achieved during Electric Arc Furnace steelmaking?

Tags: metallurgy

In the basic oxygen process, steel is made from pig iron (having a high carbon content) by oxidising the carbon with a high-pressure oxygen lance.

In an EAF, steel is made mostly from scrap, but it can also be made from raw materials such as Pig Iron, Direct-Reduced Iron, and Cementite (from the [Iron Carbide Process](https://www.ispatguru.com/process-for-manufacturing-of-iron-carbide/)).

Direct-reduced iron and Cementite still have relatively high carbon content compared to the desired amount in most steels.
In case steel is made primarily from these raw materials in the EAF, how is it decarburized? If it uses oxygen for this, how does this process essentially differ from Basic Oxygen steelmaking?